# Как переименовать файл/папку с пробелами в имени

Tags: python

В одной папке следующие файлы с пробелами в именах:

> 'a'
>
> 'a a'
>
> a a
>
> a a a

Хочу переименовать файл а а в файл а.
Как мне это объяснить методу `os.rename()`?
Особенно если имена файлов вводит пользователь в интерфейсе какой либо программы и только потом они передаются в `os.rename()` **одной строкой за 1 раз**.
Например:

```
import os


def my_rename(arg):
    source_dest = arg.split()
    source = source_dest[0]
    dest = source_dest[1]
    try:
        os.rename(source, dest)
        print("%s renamed to %s successfully." % (source, dest))

    # If Source is a file
    # but destination is a directory
    except IsADirectoryError:
        print("Source is a file but destination is a directory.")

    # If source is a directory
    # but destination is a file
    except NotADirectoryError:
        print("Source is a directory but destination is a file.")

    # For permission related errors
    except PermissionError:
        print("Operation not permitted.")

    # For other errors
    except OSError as error:
        print(error)

my_rename(input('enter source destination '))
```

Comment: Имя файла с пробелами и спецсимволами должно экранироваться кавычками

Comment: И как имя 'a a', где кавычки в имени файла отличить от 'a a', где кавычки это экранирование?

Comment: `"\"a\""` - будет "a"

Comment: https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/stroki-literaly-strok.html

Comment: можно еще или `' "a" '`(добавил пробелы чтобы было хорошо видно)

Comment: @Keymaster с помощью экранирования, конечно же. Как еще?